# Android AB testing xml layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ab-testing

I'm trying to find an easy way to AB test layout, note that the layouts that I'm talking about are minor changes in views width, height, text-size, margins... the main problem is that a single test that requires to change a few of those parameters requires me:

- Create duplicate layouts with just minor changes
- Or change those parameters after the view is inflated

I tried to implement a `LayoutInflater.Factory` that will go over the XML attributes and override them in the following menor:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    override:layout_height="resolveHeightForABtest()" 
    />
```

when the factory sees an override attribute, it overrides the original (calling the specified method via reflection).
The implementation is not that complex however, the original class that implements the `LayoutInflater.Factory` interface, seems impossible to obtain the instance without reflection. (I need to delegate the view creation to this class. I don't want to reimplement it.

**Any ideas on how it can be achieve? not necessarily the solution above, but anything that can simplify AB testing with multiple layouts could be awesome!**

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to look at the AB testing capabilities provided my Mixpanel. You can tweak things without pushing an app update. I haven't used it personally but though that I should share it with you: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android#ab_testing